# Finding specific data in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query from which to search for a given column name in a database. However, I'd like to be able to show the first line of the column as well so I can see what data is contained within the columns.

Is there an effective way to do this?

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
           ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%Insert Data Here%'
ORDER BY    TableName
           ,ColumnName;
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server` etc..) that you are using.

Comment: You are going to need to use `dynamic sql` for this.

Comment: Azure SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a select into a variable and execute it like below. You may run into issues depending on your data types (for example, I have a column that results in this message depending on my search value

> Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed.

For normal data types, however, this should work for you:

```
DECLARE @searchKey NVARCHAR(100) = 'name' --this is what you're looking for in the column name
    , @selectCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @selectCommand = COALESCE(@selectCommand + ' union all ','') + 'select top 1 '''+ i.COLUMN_NAME+''' AS ColumnName, ''['+ i.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+ i.TABLE_NAME+']'' AS TableName, try_convert(varchar(max),'+ i.COLUMN_NAME+') AS SampleData FROM ['+ i.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+ i.TABLE_NAME+'] '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i 
WHERE i.COLUMN_NAME LIKE N'%'+@searchKey+'%'
EXEC(@selectCommand)
```

Results look like this with a @searchKey of 'name':

```
ColumnName   TableName              SampleData
name         [dbo].[table_1]        person 1
NAME         [dbo].[asffaef]        rose
name         [dbo].[tablefeoe]      ashely
DatabaseName [dbo].[Untitled - 3]   NULL
LoginName    [dbo].[Untitled - 3]   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought you could do this in a single `dymaic sql` statement, but then realized that wouldn't work.  So unfortunately this is one of those cases where you have to use a `cursor` with `dynamic sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (tableName varchar(100), columnName varchar(100), val varchar(max))

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500) 
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(100)

DECLARE tables_columns_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT      c.name  AS ColumnName
           ,t.name AS TableName
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%Insert Data Here%'
ORDER BY    TableName
           ,ColumnName;

OPEN tables_columns_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_columns_cursor INTO @ColumnName, @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO #Results 
                      SELECT TOP 1 ''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS ColumnName
                           , ''' + @TableName + ''' AS TableName
                           , ' + @ColumnName + ' 
                      FROM ' + @TableName

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_columns_cursor INTO @ColumnName, @TableName
END
CLOSE tables_columns_cursor
DEALLOCATE tables_columns_cursor

SELECT * FROM #Results
DROP TABLE #Results
```